# Can I use a Canada-licensed car for the NJ road test?

Tags: driving-license, car

Can I use a Canada-licensed car for the NJ road test? I don't have canadian license but my partner would like to drive down to NJ for my drive test.

I wonder if I can use them as long as it meets all the other requirements.

Answer (score 3):

A vehicle licensed in Canada cannot be used for a New Jersey driving test.

The [New Jersey Driver's Manual](https://www.state.nj.us/mvc/pdf/license/drivermanual.pdf) says this on page 34:

> **ROAD TEST CHECKLIST**
>
> No practice driving is permitted on the test course or in the parallel parking area. Every road test applicant must bring all the items on this checklist
> to the road test site to take the test. Only ORIGINAL documents will be accepted.
>
> - 6 points of ID.
> - Validated permit (permit must be legible and cannot be laminated).
> - Valid inspection sticker on vehicle or official “No Inspection Sticker Required” card, valid registration card and valid insurance ID card or electronic version for vehicle used for the test (unless covered by BPU or federal DOT regulations)...
>
> *(additional items omitted)*

The third bullet point requires the car used in a driver's test to display a valid inspection sticker or official "No inspection Sticker Required" card. This will require that the testing car be licensed in New Jersey.

EDIT 12-5-22

In Comments, @phoog points out:

> At the bottom of the road test checklist is a box saying "vehicles registered out of state must comply with the laws of the motorist’s home state about insurance identification." This implies that vehicles aren't required to be registered in New Jersey, though any impact that this might have on the inspection sticker requirement is not made clear.

I agree. The conflict between the express requirement and the implication that a non-NJ car can qualify if it has "insurance identification" is not resolved in this document. I don't know which approach would be taken by the testing center, or if they'd even notice. There's risk here: it'd be a lot of extra work and expense to drive a car down from Canada and then find the New Jersey MVC won't accept it.

Comment: At the bottom of the road test checklist is a box saying "vehicles registered out of state must comply with the laws of the 
motorist’s home state about insurance identification."  This implies that vehicles aren't required to be registered in New Jersey, though any impact that this might have on the inspection sticker requirement is not made clear.

Comment: Why would the "valid inspection sticker" requirement imply a NJ sticker? Other jurisdictions have their own stickers. This is my personal experience and in WA, but still: I moved from BC to WA for work and it took me months to sort out importing my car and registering it in WA. In that time, one of my new co-workers asked if anyone could lend her a car for her test and I offered. The examiner apparently did call me to confirm that my Canadian insurance would still be valid for them, but had no issues otherwise.

Comment: @Eugene I agree that the words "valid inspection sticker" might be understood to include stickers from other states or countries. OTOH, I think it's clearer that the just-previous reference to "validated permit" refers to a NJ permit, which in turn  suggests they're all supposed to be NJ documents. The last two sentences of the answer still apply.